# does hibernate envers support editing existing historical data?

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way to update an existing historical data generated by hibernate envers, currently I only know how to retrieve the historical data, but don't know any ways to edit the existing historical data, does anyone have any good idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Editing audit data kind of defeats the purpose of auditing, no? You can use native SQL though to do that if you really want.